# Unable to get the components once i logged in using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

i'm new to framework and my objective is to show header and sidebar only when We logged in through localStorage. I couldn't able to show header and sidebar after logging in. Couldn't able to give routing properly. Can anyone please help me in this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Make use state for each input, put the on change on the input like so.

```
<TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="email"
            label="Email Address"
            name="email"
            autoComplete="email"
            autoFocus
            onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}  // Here
          />
```

Comment: the routing is not happening :(. I don't know where I'm going wrong

Comment: I removed the value property, I missed that originally.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should add props on Container component
Like this :

```
function Login () {
    const [logged, loggedSet] = useState(false)

    const onSubmit = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      loggedSet(true)
    }

    ...
    <Container logged={logged}>
     ...
    </Container>
  }
export default Login;
```

Next step is check logged props in Container function:

```
function Container (props) {
     const logged = props.logged 
     return (
       <div className='wrapper'>
        {logged && <Header/>}
         ...
        {logged && <Sidebar/>}
      </div>
     );
}
export default Container;
```